# Performing maximum likelihood estimation for SIR Model

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, systems-biology

The code first produces a plot of the dataset, then simulates the SIR model using the parameter values we found in the manual calibration to the full dataset of the total number infected .

```
(*total size of population*) n = 763;

(*days*)
tmax = 14;

(*Flu dataset*)
numberinfected = {3, 8, 26, 76, 225, 298, 258, 233, 189, 128, 68, 29, 
   14, 4};

pointsPlot = 
 ListPlot[numberinfected, PlotStyle -> Purple, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time (days)", "Number Infected"}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Total cases"}]
```

[image]

```
*Set parameter values*)
{\[Beta], \[Gamma]} = {1.7, 0.45};

(*Define the SIR model equations*)
sireqns = {s'[t] == -\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n, 
   i'[t] == \[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n - \[Gamma]*i[t], 
   r'[t] == \[Gamma]*i[t]};

initialConditions = {s[0] == n, i[0] == 1, r[0] == 0};

(*Solve the differential equations*)
sol = NDSolve[{sireqns, initialConditions}, {s, i, r}, {t, 0, tmax}];

(*Extract the infected values from the solution*)
infectedValues = i /. sol[[1]];
fitPlot = 
 Plot[infectedValues[t], {t, 1, 14}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Simulated infected"}];
Show[pointsPlot, fitPlot, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now, we want to calculate the likelihood of the model with these specific parameter values, i . e . the probability of observing these numbers of reported cases given our simulated numbers of infected people .

We are building up to calibrating the SIR model to our flu outbreak data from previous exercises using **likelihood** as a measure of the divergence between the model projections and the data. This time, even though we are looking at the same outbreak, the dataset only shows the **reported cases**, and we know that 60 % of flu cases are reported.

```
(*Adjust infected values for reporting rate*)adjustedInfectedValues = 
 infectedValues*0.6

(*Simulated reported cases*)
simulatedReportedCases = Round[adjustedInfectedValues]

(*Likelihood calculation*)
likelihood = 
  Product[Exp[-\[Lambda]] \[Lambda]^k/k!, {\[Lambda], 
    simulatedReportedCases}];

(*Print the likelihood value*)
Print["Likelihood:", likelihood]
```

[image]

Comment: Usually likelihoods are L~Exp[-(yi-y[x[i]])^2/2], so you're missing a minus sign there, but I haven't ran the code, perhaps it's also something else.

Comment: @HansOlo Unfortunately it does not work

Comment: @HansOlo Let’s take it a step back, can you explain that to me?

Comment: The immediate cause of the $RecursionLimit error is that `k` is undefined and `{\[Lambda], simulatedReportedCases}` does not provide a list of `\[Lambda]` values.  But the underlying issue is that you haven't given a mathematical definition of the likelihood (or the log of the likelihood).  I suggest asking the question about the likelihood of this model at CrossValidated (http://stats.stackexchange.com) and then back here for implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(*Provided data*)
numberinfected = {3, 8, 26, 76, 225, 298, 258, 233, 189, 128, 68, 29, 
   14, 4};

(*Parameters*)
{\[Beta], \[Gamma]} = {1.7, 0.45};
n = 763; (*Total population*)
underreportingFactor = 0.6;
tmax = 14;

(*Define the SIR model equations with underreporting*)
sireqns = {s'[t] == -\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n, 
   i'[t] == (\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n - \[Gamma]*i[t]), 
   r'[t] == \[Gamma]*i[t]};

(*Initial conditions*)
initialConditions = {s[0] == n, i[0] == 1, r[0] == 0};

(*Solve the SIR model equations*)
sirSol = 
  NDSolve[{sireqns, initialConditions}, {s, i, r}, {t, 0, tmax - 1}];

(*Calculate reported cases from the model*)
reportedCasesModel[t_] := (i[t] /. sirSol)*underreportingFactor;

(*Plot reported cases from the model and the actual dataset*)
modelPlot = 
  Plot[reportedCasesModel[t], {t, 0, tmax - 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Purple, Dashed, Thick}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Reported cases "}];

dataPlot = 
  ListPlot[numberinfected, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Total cases"}];

Show[modelPlot, dataPlot, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time (days)", "Reported Cases"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Reported Cases: Model vs Data", PlotRange -> All]
```

I am still struggling to calculate likelihood
[image]

Answer (score 6):

- `ParametricNDSolve` and `NonlinearModelFit` work for this cases.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 763;
tmax = 14;
numberinfected = {3, 8, 26, 76, 225, 298, 258, 233, 189, 128, 68, 29, 
   14, 4};
pointsPlot = 
 ListPlot[numberinfected, PlotStyle -> Purple, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time (days)", "Number Infected"}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Total cases"}]; 
sireqns = {s'[t] == -β*s[t]*
    i[t]/n, i'[t] == β*s[t]*i[t]/n - γ*i[t], 
  r'[t] == γ*i[t]};

initialConditions = {s[0] == n, i[0] == 1, r[0] == 0};
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{sireqns, initialConditions}, {s, i, r}, {t, 
        0, tmax}, {β, γ}];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[numberinfected, 
    i[β, γ]@t /. sol, {β, γ}, t]
Show[ListPlot[numberinfected], 
  Plot[nlm[t], {t, 0, 14}, PlotStyle -> Orange]]
```

```
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

> `{β -> 1.66747, γ -> 0.444057}`

[image]

Comment: my problem is how I could calculate the likelihood of reported cases in the above situation

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos Yes, I solve the original problem,the newly edited problem I think we need time to understand.

Comment: To be clearer I want to calculate the likelihood and design the reported cases